# How to change the position of buttons in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatables

I have the following codes:

```js
var dataSet = [
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    data: dataSet,
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel'],
    columns: [{
      title: "Name"
    }, {
      title: "Position"
    }, {
      title: "Office"
    }, {
      title: "Extn."
    }, {
      title: "Start date"
    }, {
      title: "Salary"
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

What I want to do is to change the button location to the center, like this:

[image]

How can achieve that?

Comment: there are no buttons (copy, excel) in your snippet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use the following CSS rule. Please note that it will target all tables on the page. Use more specific rule to target one table only.

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-buttons {
  float:none;  
  text-align:center;
}
```

Also in order for it to work you need to use `dom: 'lfBrtip'`. See [`dom`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option for more details.

> **DEMO**

```js
var dataSet = [
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'lfBrtip',
    data: dataSet,
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel'],
    columns: [{
      title: "Name"
    }, {
      title: "Position"
    }, {
      title: "Office"
    }, {
      title: "Extn."
    }, {
      title: "Start date"
    }, {
      title: "Salary"
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-buttons {
  float:none;  
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,jszip-2.5.0,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3,b-html5-1.0.3/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,jszip-2.5.0,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3,b-html5-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's not the perfect solution but it will save your day for sure. Great 1+ for that.

Answer (score 0):

give css dt-buttons what you want to change button,

```
.dt-buttons{
left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method (in addition to the accepted answer) to do this is to increase the width of the div, which contains the buttons. And than you can use **float: right** for specific button/buttons for moving it to the center.

To increase the width of the div use following code -

```
 $("div#example_wrapper").find($(".dt-buttons")).css("width", "400px");
```

Note that the value of **width** may need to re-adjust.

And than for moving buttons -

```
var styles = {
    position: "relative",
    float: "right"
};

$("div#example_wrapper").find($(".dt-buttons")).find($("a")).css(styles);
```

In this case, you don't need to use `dom: 'lfBrtip'`

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/ggLak8e1/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can see this link for reference if you are using "TableTools" constructor for [Direct Initiallization](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/initialisation#Direct-initialisation), this extension has now been retired and has been replaced by the [Buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/).

Answer (score 0):

Using **jQuery** and **css**:

```
$('.dt-buttons').css('text-align', 'right');
```

OR

Using **jQuery** and **bootstrap4**:

```
$('.dt-buttons').addClass('text-right');
```